# Como fazer uma div ser posicionada como um bloco no meio de outra div?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

A princípio, a pergunta pode parecer esquisita, mas meu problema é o seguinte:

Até o momento, eu possuo a tela abaixo:
[image: Imagem da tela]

Mas o que eu quero fazer é criar um bloco, como o da estrutura circulada abaixo, como se fosse um blog ou algo do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O CSS que fiz dessa div e da que está embaixo até o momento é esse:

```
.lateralesquerda{ /*bloco da aba lateral com as informações de contato*/
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    border-right: 1px dotted;
    float: left;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    margin-top: -15pt;
    margin-left:-6pt;
}
.lateraldireita{ /*bloco da lateral que agirá como um blog*/
    position: relative;
}
.experiencia{ /*bloco que quero deixar no meio do bloco direito*/
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width: 50%
     top: 20pt;
     left: 20pt;
     padding: 0pt;
     margin: 0pt;
     background-color: white;
 }
```

E esta é a minha estrutura HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="lateralesquerda">
            <div class="descricao">
                <figure>
                    <img src="./_img/teste.jpg" alt="Arthur Siqueira"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h3>Arthur Siqueira</h3>
                        <p>Estudante de Engenharia de Software</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <div class="blocosesq biografia">
                    <p class="biografia">Estudante de Engenharia de Software na Univates.</p>
                    <p class="biografia">Iniciante no desenvolvimento Web</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blocosesq contato">

                <div class="fone">
                    <p>(00) 0 0000-0000</p>
                    <h5>Mobile</h5>
                </div>

                <div class="email">
                    <p>email1</p>
                    <h5>Pessoal</h5>

                    <p>email2</p>
                    <h5>Institucional</h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blocosesq endereco">
                <p>cidade</p>
                <p>cep</p>
                <h5>Endereço residencial</h5>

                <p>cidade</p>
                <p>cep</p>
                <h5>Endereço para contato</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="blocosesq habilidades">
                <h5>Habilidades Profissionais</h5>
                A <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
                B <progress value="25" max="100"></progress>
                C <progress value="10" max="100"></progress>
                D <progress value="20" max="100"></progress>
                E <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
    </div>
    <aside class="lateraldireita">
        <div class="experiencia">
        <h3>Experiências Profissionais</h3>
        Experiencia profissional        
     </div>
        <div class="educacao">
            <h3>Educação</h3>

            <div class="curso">
                Engenharia de Software - Univates
                AGO 2018 - CURSANDO
            </div>
            <div class="curso">
                Técnico em Informática - Escola Estadual de Educação Profissional Estrela - EEEPE
                JAN 2014 - DEZ 2018
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="interesses">
            <h3>Interesses</h3>
            <i class="fas fa-guitar"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i>
        </div>
    </aside>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Obrigado pelo auxílio

Comment: Cara sem ver a estrutura do seu HTML não da para te ajudar muito. Edite sua pergunta e inclua tb o código HTML

Comment: Adicionado. Obrigado pela contribuição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara basicamente faltou um `float:left` na classe `.lateraldireita`

```
.lateraldireita {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Código

**OBS:** Como vc ainda não fez os `@media` para tratar a responsividade aqui o layout vai ficar quebrado, mas **exiba em página toda** para ver o resultado ai

```css
.lateralesquerda{ /*bloco da aba lateral com as informações de contato*/
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    border-right: 1px dotted;
    float: left;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    margin-top: -15pt;
    margin-left:-6pt;
}
.lateraldireita{ /*bloco da lateral que agirá como um blog*/
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.experiencia{ /*bloco que quero deixar no meio do bloco direito*/
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
     top: 20pt;
     left: 20pt;
     padding: 0pt;
     margin: 0pt;
     background-color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div class="lateralesquerda">
    <div class="descricao">
        <figure>
            <img src="./_img/teste.jpg" alt="Arthur Siqueira" />
            <figcaption>
                <h3>Arthur Siqueira</h3>
                <p>Estudante de Engenharia de Software</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="blocosesq biografia">
            <p class="biografia">Estudante de Engenharia de Software na Univates.</p>
            <p class="biografia">Iniciante no desenvolvimento Web</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocosesq contato">

        <div class="fone">
            <p>(00) 0 0000-0000</p>
            <h5>Mobile</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="email">
            <p>email1</p>
            <h5>Pessoal</h5>

            <p>email2</p>
            <h5>Institucional</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocosesq endereco">
        <p>cidade</p>
        <p>cep</p>
        <h5>Endereço residencial</h5>

        <p>cidade</p>
        <p>cep</p>
        <h5>Endereço para contato</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="blocosesq habilidades">
        <h5>Habilidades Profissionais</h5>
        A <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
        B <progress value="25" max="100"></progress>
        C <progress value="10" max="100"></progress>
        D <progress value="20" max="100"></progress>
        E <progress value="30" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
</div>
<aside class="lateraldireita">
    <div class="experiencia">
        <h3>Experiências Profissionais</h3>
        Experiencia profissional
    </div>
    <div class="educacao">
        <h3>Educação</h3>

        <div class="curso">
            Engenharia de Software - Univates
            AGO 2018 - CURSANDO
        </div>
        <div class="curso">
            Técnico em Informática - Escola Estadual de Educação Profissional Estrela - EEEPE
            JAN 2014 - DEZ 2018
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interesses">
        <h3>Interesses</h3>
        <i class="fas fa-guitar"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i>
    </div>
</aside>
<footer>
</footer>
```